# Update application.properties values with ansbile

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ansible, properties-file

How to update values in spring's application.properties while deploying with ansibile scripts.

I could use ansible's lineinfile module and replace values with regex. But I'm looking for a better solution.

EDIT: Using Ansible jinja template is another solution. But with this whenever I something in the application.properties of spring, I should also be adding it in the template. However I want it to be in one place.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [template](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/template_module.html) with [Jinja Templating](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-container/container_yml/template.html) module for this. You will need to create template .j2 file that will look like:

```
logging.level.root={{logging_level_root}}
endpoints.enabled={{endpoints_enabled}}
```

Values in `{{}}` are resolved from variables that are typically stored in inventory files for each environment. `lineinfile` is useful in different situation - typically replacing line in file.

Comment: Whenever I add something in application.properties in spring file, I should also adding it in the jinja template. However I want it to be in one place.

Comment: If you want your properties in one place create `application.properties` file and use ansible copy module.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning it previously. In local dev environment, I don't use ansible deployment. So there should be a application.properties in spring file. During ansible deployment, I'm left with the option of using regex match and replace.

Comment: By local dev you mean your laptop or some environment for developers team? If seconnd, I would advise to use ansible scripts for installation of such environment. As for two places where you have properties - you will have as many places as many environments you have. You will specify property value for 5 environments in 5 inventories so you will add another line with property in template file

Comment: Typically you check out the code and run. You don't do an ansible deploy when developing.